# What does a beep sound mean from a working hard disk?

Tags: hard-drive, hard-drive-recovery, noise, bad-sectors, hard-drive-failure

I have a laptop of 7 years old with a 2TB Seagate hard disk. About 2 years ago I heard a loud beep sound and it didn't happen again after months. But nowadays the intervals between the beep sound get's smaller and I can hear it almost once per day!

But I guess the problem is about a specific section of the hard drive I have installed Ubuntu, because I have 2 OS on this machine and Windows uses first 1.5TB and Ubuntu rest 0.5TB. And I hear this noise almost always when I am on the Ubuntu.

Is there any way that I can find that defected part of the hard drive and isolate it and save my hard drive for 6 months or 1 year later?

`EDIT`: I forgot to say after about 2 seconds of a loud beep sound, it ends up with a clunk sound it seems the hard drives header/reader goes to it's starting position(Although these are only my assumptions).

Comment: More info is needed. What does the beep mean? Is it on boot? See https://kb.iu.edu/d/afzy . What leads you to believe it the *HDD* that beeps? There is no speaker in the HDD. If you believe there are bad sectors, have you scanned in Windows (https://www.easeus.com/disk-copy/clone-resource/repair-a-bad-sector-in-windows-10-8-7.html) or in Ubuntu (https://www.linuxtechi.com/check-hard-drive-for-bad-sector-linux/)?

Comment: You should make sure there's a current backup at hand.

Comment: Does [Everything You Need to Know About Hard Drive Beeping - DriveSavers](https://drivesaversdatarecovery.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-hard-drive-beeping/) answer your question?

Comment: This is not good - save your data, to be safe in case of disk failure.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik: It's a loud beep sound about 2 seconds and happens after the OS is loaded up and running randomly.

Comment: since hdd's don't have speaker, they're not supposed to beep.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik: I tried `sudo smartctl -H /dev/sdb` on all partitions from 1 to 9 and they all said PASSED!

Comment: @JoepvanSteen: So where does this beep sound come from? I thought maybe some mechanical issues cause this on HDD?

Comment: @JoepvanSteen: I also added some more explanation on the EDIT part.

Comment: I've once encountered similar situation; loud beep-like sound from a spinning disk, then a clunk. Never figured out what caused the sound, but that disk died in a very short order.

Answer (score 1):

What you presented as a fact

> What does a beep sound mean from a working hard disk?

becomes a mere suspicion of yours:

> About 2 years ago I heard a loud beep sound and it didn't happen again after months.

I can't figure out the difference between BIOS beeps and hard drive beeps (if there are any HDD beeps at all possible without a speaker in there).

You spoke about the need to "isolating the part" but you did not properly isolate the HDD as the potential source of noise.

To isolate the source of noise, reboot your laptop with any key pressed down.
Does that yield a beep?
If yes you have learn't the sound of your BIOS beeping.

If there is no beep, remove the HDD from your laptop and attach your HDD **externally** to your laptop or another computer so that you are able to hear where the noise is coming from.

Any internal connection via SATA ports that are connected to your chipset directly bears the risk that your BIOS is beeping (maybe as a reaction to a HDD failure condition in that moment.

> Is there any way that I can find that defected part of the hard drive and isolate it and save my hard drive for 6 months or 1 year later?

Maybe, but this way is no economical solution for your problem. The least thing to do is to backup your drive. Check the SMART parameters of your drive. The fact that you are asking the question suggests that you don't have the knowledge, the experience, the tools and the necessary environment.

Manufacturers can repair broken drives and professional data recovery can do this, too. Both have different targets in mind: The manufacturer does it for a profit and the recovery professional does it to enable a last duplication of a previous faulty drive.

Answer (score 0):

> I forgot to say after about 2 seconds of a loud beep sound, it ends up with a clunk sound it seems the hard drives header/reader goes to it's starting position

Linux may be powering the drive off after it's not used for a while.  [See if you can change the standby setting for your drive.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/891173/disable-spinning-down-of-hdd-in-16-04)

> I have a laptop of 7 years old with a 2TB Seagate hard disk.

7 years old is a long service time for a mechanical hard drive.  You should plan to replace it and back up any important data now.

Comment: In terms of possible capacitor degradation I agree with your statement on 7 years. To make a judgment about all the rest I'd like to see the SMART parameters - an age of 7 years does not necessarily mean permanent operation...